# How to create multiple layout in react js and react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a web app where, I  want two layouts when the user type is admin show the dashboard layout and when the user is employee so form layout. First it must show only login page and land the user according to the type.

This is my routes array which is in one folder.

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Login,
    exact: true,
    layout:  DashboardLayout 
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    exact: true,
    layout: DashboardLayout 
  },
  {
    path: "/editor",
    component: CompanyAbout,
    exact: true,
    layout:  DashboardLayout 
  },


const renderRoutes = (routes) => {
  routes.map((route) => {
    const RouteComponent = route.component
    const Layout = route.layout
    return (
      <Route
        exact={route.exact}
        path={route.path}
        render={(props) => (
          <Layout>
            <RouteComponent {...props} />
          </Layout>
        )}
      />
    );
  });
};

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Router>
          <Row>
            <Col md={12}>
              <Switch>
                {renderRoutes(routes)}
              </Switch>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          {/* <Row>
            <Footer />
          </Row> */}
        </Router>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my app.js file please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: We need more details about the current behavior you see in order to know what you mean by "what you're doing wrong". We also would need to know how you're determining if a user is an admin or non-admin user.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot close the array , routes = [];